# Error while executing .go file. Not recognized even when go is installed

Tags: go

When I type go run file.go in command line, it says go is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. I have Go installed.

Edit: sorry that was a weird question

Comment: How exactly did you install it?

Comment: golang.org/dl the msi file i think

Answer (score 2):

You should put the directory where you installed Go (default `c:\Go\bin`)  in your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: @AryamaanGoswamy You should watch this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_b-9kcq-xmA